# How test unauthorized method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have controller `Post` with typical CRUD method's.
I have a PostPolicy, in which:

```
public function destroy(User $user, Post $post)
{
    $user->id === $post->author_id;
}
```

I want to write test for this. When I check if user delete his own post - all OK.

But when I test if other user user can delete not his own post, laravel test send error:

```
Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException: This action is unauthorized.
```

How bypass it or which has another method for write this test?

Code

```
 <?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\Feeds\Feed;
use App\Models\User;
use Tests\SphinxConnection;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
class PolicyTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations,
        SphinxConnection;

    public function testFeedPolicy()
    {
        $this->expectException(\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class);

        $user1 = factory(User::class)->create([
            'id' => 1,
        ]);
        $user2 = factory(User::class)->create([
            'id' => 2,
        ]);

        factory(Post::class)->create([
            'id' => 27,
            'editor_id' => 2,
        ]);
        factory(Post::class)->create([
            'id' => 30,
            'editor_id' => 2,
        ]);

        $this->delete('/api/feeds/27', [], [
            'authorization' => "Bearer {$user2->api_token}",
            'accept' => 'application/json',
        ])->assertJson([

        ]);;
        $this->delete('/api/feeds/30', [], [
            'authorization' => "Bearer {$user1->api_token}",
            'accept' => 'application/json',
        ])->assertJson([

        ]);;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your test?

Comment: Update post....

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to the beginning of your test method:

```
$this->expectException(\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class);
```

---

**EDIT**

Your test method could look something like:

```
/** @test */
function a_user_can_delete_their_own_post()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $post = factory(Post::class)->create([
        'editor_id' => $user->id,
    ]);

    $this->actingAs($user);

    $this
        ->delete("/api/feeds/{$post->id}", [], [
            'authorization' => "Bearer {$user->api_token}",
            'accept'        => 'application/json',
        ])
        ->assertResponseOk();

    $this->assertFalse(Post::where('id', $post->id)->exists());
}

/** @test */
function a_user_can_not_delete_a_post_they_do_not_own()
{
    $this->expectException(\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class);

    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $post = factory(Post::class)->create([
        'editor_id' => $user->id + 1,
    ]);

    $this->actingAs($user);

    $this->delete("/api/feeds/{$post->id}", [], [
        'authorization' => "Bearer {$user->api_token}",
        'accept'        => 'application/json',
    ]);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And test will be always DONE, even user can't delete post.

Comment: When I add string  which you write - test always OK, so I didn't expect the result.

Comment: @yrrtyrt Are you testing that a user can delete a post and that another user can not delete a post in the same method (function)?

Comment: I test if user1 can delete own post1, and user2 can delete post1 of user1.

Comment: @yrrtyrt Can you add your whole test method to your question (including the `function` part)?

Comment: Yes. Update post.

Comment: @yrrtyrt You are going to be much better off separating the methods to test each thing e.g. `testAUserCanDeleteTheirOwnPost` and `testAUserCanNotDeleteSomeoneElsesPost`.

Comment: Ok, but if I separate it - testAUserCanNotDeleteSomeoneElsesPost - whith string which you write will be always return OK even user can't delete post.

Comment: @yrrtyrt I've added an example to my answer

Comment: Oh, second test always return OK, always.

Comment: @yrrtyrt I forget to add `$this->actingAs($user)`. I've updated my answer.